# How to disable logs from external APIs in Android

Tags: android, logging, apk, cocos2d-x

I have a Cocos2d-x project and I wish to disable all the logs from the external JARs that I've attached, from Flurry to Pushwoosh, there are many external API's. Is there any way to remove the logs for these?

I tried setting, 
`android:debuggable="false"`
in the AndroidManifest.xml, but no use,

Also in proguard-project.txt, I set,

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** w(...);
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** i(...);
}
```

But still in the Release build, the logs are being seen. Any help on this would be great!